# How does compiler/stdlib determine what policy to use for default std::async

Tags: c++

Edit: Sorry that I did something stupid. This question is wrong. Just go ahead to the answer or vote to close this question in case of wasting other's time.

---

I know that compilers and/or standard libaray are free to choose what policy to use for `std::async` with default policy. But how do they determine that?

This program has really confusing behavior.

```cpp
// extern.cpp

#include <future>

extern std::future<void> a;

void task(int t);

void extern_func1() {
  a.get();
}

void extern_func2() {
  task(2);
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;

auto now_sec() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  auto t = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
  return duration_cast<seconds>(t).count();
}

template<class...Args>
void log(Args&&...args) {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "thread#" << std::this_thread::get_id() << " "
      << "time:" << now_sec() << " ";
  (..., (oss << args << " "));
  oss << "\n";
  std::string msg = oss.str();
  std::unique_lock l{m};
  std::cout << msg;
  std::cout.flush();
}

void task(int t) {
  log("task", t, "begin");
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
  log("task", t, "end");
}

std::future<void> a;

void extern_func1();
void extern_func2();

int main() {
  auto t1 = now_sec();
  a = std::async(task, 1);

#if 1
  extern_func1();    // <---- This order uses "deferred" policy(See below)
  extern_func2();
#else
  extern_func2();    // <---- This order uses async policy
  extern_func1();
#endif

  auto t2 = now_sec();
  log("total", t2 - t1, "secs");
}
```

If `extern_func1` is called before `extern_func2`, the program use "deferred" policy and outputs

```
thread#0x16da17000 time:1648037227 task 1 begin 
thread#0x16da17000 time:1648037230 task 1 end 
thread#0x1026e0580 time:1648037230 task 2 begin 
thread#0x1026e0580 time:1648037233 task 2 end 
thread#0x1026e0580 time:1648037233 total 6 secs
```

It's not the standard deferred policy because a new thread is spawned. But it starts when result is requested.

If If `extern_func2` is called before `extern_func1`, the program use async policy and outputs

```
thread#0x102970580 time:1648037352 task 2 begin 
thread#0x16d80f000 time:1648037352 task 1 begin 
thread#0x102970580 time:1648037355 task 2 end 
thread#0x16d80f000 time:1648037355 task 1 end 
thread#0x102970580 time:1648037355 total 3 secs
```

The order is the only diference. Why **the order of calling external functions of exactly same signature** change the used policy or the thread scheduling? How is this possible?

Originall there's only one translation unit. In order to rule out compiler's optimization, I moved the two functions into another translation unit and compiled them with `-fno-lto` to disable link-time optimization. But still, both GCC and Clang gives this confusing behavior.

Clang's version:

```
Homebrew clang version 13.0.1
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

GCC's version

```
g++ (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the shown output that proves that a deferred policy was used.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OK, it's not the "standard deferred policy" since a new thread was spawned. But it starts when result is requested.

Comment: How do you know it's a different policy, and not just a coincidence that you get different thread scheduling?

Comment: @user253751 Added "or the thread scheduling" to the post. I tried many times on MacOS and Ubuntu. I saw this behavior again and again. I'll feel so lucky if it's a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no policy change. Look at `extern_func1/2` again:

```
void extern_func1() {
  a.get();
}

void extern_func2() {
  task(2);
}
```

It's simply that when you call `extern_func1` first you are running:

```
a = std::async(task, 1); // start task 1
a.get(); // wait for task 1 to finish
task(2); // run task 2 on main thread
```

and when you call `extern_func2` first you are running:

```
a = std::async(task, 1); // start task 1
task(2); // run task 2 on main thread
a.get(); // wait for task 1 to finish
```

When you call `extern_func1` first, **you are preventing** both tasks from running at the same time! You are telling the computer not to run task 2 until task 1 finishes, and the computer is doing exactly what you tell it to. No weirdness here!

Comment: Uhhh, I just messed something when modifying the code and did stupid thinking. Thank you!

Comment: I will delete or close this question and "rewind" the modification  for the minimal code for orgin problem. If I still have  problem I will edit it or raise another. Thank you anyway!